# Find minimum weight of tree of graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization

Given a connected graph with $|V| = 10$ and $|E| = 20$, with $3$ edges of weight $3$, $4$ edges of weight $4$ and the remaining of weight $9$. What is the lowest weight in the subgraph spanning tree of the given graph?

I'm thinking of using the Kruskal algorithm, but have no idea how to do so, since there are no given edges.

Comment: Are you looking for the minimum among all possible graphs corresponding to the description or the worst case scenario? For the former its simpler: many edges must a spanning tree have, so what can be the minimum total weight? Then construct an explicit example realizing this weight

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the structure of the graph, it is not possible to definitively answer the question with the given information.

For example, if 3-weighted edges form a triangle ($K_3$), or 4-weighted edges form $K_3$ or $K_4$, those edges need to be deleted from the graph. But, if these edges don't belong to any clique, then the answer is easy: Since a tree with 10 vertices will have 9 edges, using 2 edges with a weight of 9 together with all 3 and 4 weighted edges will result in a spanning tree with a weight of 43.